# Change PHP Language Library in eclipse Oxygen

Tags: php, eclipse

Eclipse for PHP Developers
Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
Build id: 20170620-1800

How can I change the `PHP Language Library` to PHP 7 (see screen below)? The project results from a previous eclipse version which has been imported to Oxygen. On my machine no PHP is installed, I use `Xdebug` with a Linux VM, the workspace is on a samba share on that VM (runs PHP 7.0 on Apache).

In the preferences I can add PHP paths, but I have no access to the PHP directory on the Linux VM. But when I create a new PHP project in eclipse, I can select a PHP version (including 7.0).

I wonder if it is the only chance to create a new PHP 7.0 project and copy my files over, or is there a way to alter the PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.0?

[image: PHP eclipse]

Edit: based on [howlger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45833056/356726)

Yes, `PHP validation` solves it. [image: PHP7]

I was looking under Validation where is no such thing [image: Validation]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. **Right-click on the project** folder and choose ***Properties***
2. In the properties dialog, in ***PHP > Validation***

   1. ***Enable project specific settings***
   2. As ***PHP Version*** choose

      - ***7.0 (uniform variable syntax, scalar type hint,...)* or**
      - ***7.1 (void return types, class constant visibility,...)***

You also might configure installed PHPs: ***Window > Properties: PHP > Installed PHPs***

See also PHP help: *[PHP Interpreter Properties](https://eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/php_interpreter_properties.htm)*