# How to ensure php syntax check works in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt

My eclipse has no PHP core code completion functionality.
I tried with new downloads, no chance.

How to add the Php Language Library?

edit to add:
this occurred on an existing project which was messed up in the beginning

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install a PHP IDE plugin for Eclipse directly from the Eclipse environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397978/how-to-install-a-php-ide-plugin-for-eclipse-directly-from-the-eclipse-environmen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling the validation didnt work for me.
I fixed it by ensuring that I have a `.buildpath` file in my project's root folder.
the file looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<buildpath>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
    <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
</buildpath>
```

specifically adding this part does the job.
`<buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>`

I wasn't able to find a UI based solution (even with 3-20) - directly modifying the file worked for me

Comment: Very impressive how you found an answer yourself in almost no time. Unfortunately, I cannot even reproduce the issue. How did you create the project so that the code completion is missing? Why does it work for others and not for you?

Comment: I've been working without the core library for quite a while, with messed up project setup, pulled from left and right. I was properly annoyed yesterday and tried to figure it out, also with your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45833056/5011027.  
As it didnt work for me even with 3-20, I created a fresh project and compared all files of the new one with the old and found the difference then.
edit to add: the specific line was missing in the `.buildpath` - deleting the line might reproduce the issue